# Implementing a 'Remember me' function

Tags: php, cookies, parse-platform

I was hoping somebody could help me out with how I would implement a 'Remember me' function in Parse.

When the ParseUser is first created, a ParseSession is also created with them, however this has an expiry date of 1 year. The problem is, the expiryDate is read-only, so I'm not able to change this. Even then, I am confused as to how these ParseSession's work, as they don't actually store any cookies.

Should I just delete the ParseSession's that are automatically created on registration, and make my own cookie and session to deal with this, or does Parse provide an easier way?

---

Edit with code I have tried so far:

So far I have tried to do this without Parse, using PHP's own cookie functions:

```
$user = ParseUser::logIn($email, $password);
$_SESSION['mySession'] = serialize($user);
$_SESSION['start'] = time(); // Taking now logged in time.
if ($rememberMe) {
    // End session in 1 month.
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (31 * 24 * 60 * 60);
} else {
    // End session in 1 hour.
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5);
}
$parseSession = $user->getSessionToken();
// Note I got stuck here as I realised the expiryDate is readOnly in the docs.
```

Note that this code right now isn't working as expected since the session I am creating using

```
session_start();
ParseClient::setStorage(new ParseSessionStorage());
```

seems to be creating a session that lasts only the browser session - but I will look into this and I believe/hope it's something to do with PHP storing the sessions (I checked the .ini and it said on Windows I need to configure it manually which I have not done yet).

Comment: give more details now it's unclear

Comment: @Robert Details on ParseServer can be found [over here](https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide#sessions) but what I'm wanting to do is store the session for 1 hour without Remember me, or for 1 month with Remember me. However, I'm unsure how Parse would allow me to do this and whether I would just have to use PHP's cookie's instead.

Comment: We are not here to write code for you, show us what you have tried! I can't know what you want or tried with just words, it get's really hard to help you that way.

Comment: Hey @Nytrix - I've updated my answer to include the code I've tried to far. Thanks :)

Comment: I feel like you got the concept of `remember me` wrong. You need to use cookies. You save a key in a cookie, you save that same key in a database, then you cross check if those keys are correct. That way you have a safe way of remembering users.

Comment: @Nytrix Yes, I just thought that Parse would actually deal with this for me since it creates a session in the database each time, but weirdly it doesn't actually create any cookie, hence why I had to do this manually. I guess the way forward with this is only through PHP cookies in this case then, so I'll give that a go.

Comment: @harryjamesuk Is it working now? I don't know Parse, so that makes my response a bit unfair... Hope you found your ways!

Comment: Hey again @Nytrix - Appreciate the help but I haven't found a **perfect** solution just yet. I've managed to make my own cookie, it's just that then because Parse makes its own sessions, I'll technically have two session objects which gets a bit confusing... Right now I'm trying to see whether I can make my own ParseSession objects to counter this issue and once I get a working method, I'll answer my own question here if nobody beats me to it :)